# How do day-traders or frequent traders handle their taxes?

Tags: united-states, stocks, taxes

I have been making significantly more frequent trades from my brokerage account, and it just occurred to me that this would create a lot of work during tax time.  Usually, one has to enter each stock sale that is made during the year.  So my question is do people who make frequent stock trades have to account for every single trade they make or is there a less time consuming way to complete this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this. The first is that the better brokers, such as Charles Schwab, will produce summaries of your gains and losses (using historical cost information), as well as your trades, on a monthly and annual basis. These summaries are "ready made" for the IRS. More brokers will provide these summaries come 2011.

The second is that if you are a "frequent trader" (see IRS rulings for what constitutes one), then they'll allow you to use the net worth method of accounting. That is, you take the account balance at the end of the year, subtract the beginning balance, adjust the value up for withdrawals and down for infusions, and the summary is your gain or loss.

A third way is to do all your trading in say, an IRA, which is taxed on distribution, not on stock sales.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "frequent trader" classification is about as clear as mud, and difficult to meet. If you hold investments more than 1 year, or have a day job, you're not a trader.

Answer (score 5):

Starting of 2011, your broker has to keep track of all the transactions and the cost basis, and it will be reported on your 1099-B.

Also, some brokers allow downloading the data directly to your tax software or to excel charts (I use E*Trade, and last year TurboTax downloaded all the transaction directly from them).

Comment: +1 for the TurboTax will download for you. This takes away the manual nature of this issue. Great point.

Answer (score 2):

You need to track every buy and sell to track your gains, or more likely, losses. Yes, you report each and every transactions. Pages of schedule D.